# Flash path to AndroidSDK ADB tool

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, sdk, air

I'm new to app-developing and I'm creating an Android app with Flash CS5.5.

On http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac-2ae4ef8612b2d078909-8000.html adobe says that you have to "Enter the path to the ADB tool in the tools subdirectory of the Android SDK", in the the deployment tab of AIR Android Settings. 
The problem is that then I open that tab, the place to enter the path isn't there. 
So, have I skipped an step?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that then I open that tab, the place to enter the path isn't there.

I get same situation in flash CS6. But I have successfully created application for android without specifying path to the ADB tool. I suppose flash have its own internal instance of ADB tool

just in case adb tool on my computer situated here: C:\Program Files\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

Comment: Thanks. But I can't test app once I've saved it ("application descriptor file cannot be parsed").